# Any space $X$ with the indiscrete topology is compact.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let $\tau_X = \{ \varnothing, X \} $. Let $A \subseteq X$, Let $O$ be an open cover of $A$. Since topology on $X$ is finite, then $O$ must finite too. Obviously, any subcover $O'$ of $O$ must be finite, therefore $X$ must be compact by definition.

Is this correct? It seems obvious to write it down or probably im missing somthing? any feedback? thanks

Comment: You don't need to point out that all subcovers are finite, but rather that there exists a finite subcover, namely $O$.

Comment: Same is true for connected, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't even need to consider $A\subseteq X$. What you must show is that *any* open cover of $X$ contains at least one finite subcover of $X$. But note that the *only* open cover of $X$ is the singleton $\{X\}$, and it trivially contains a finite subcover: $\{X\}$ itself.

**Addition; pointed out by @RickyDemer**: $\{\varnothing,X\}$ is another open cover of $X$, as $X\subseteq \varnothing\cup X=X$, but it is a finite cover as well.

Comment: You can do one better: Any topology with finitely many open sets (e.g. a topology on a finite set) is compact. Any open cover contains *a fortiori* a finite subcover.

Comment: @triple_sec : $\:$ $\tau_X$ is a different open cover of $X$. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer You're right, I stand corrected.